# How do I know the format of audio file?

Tags: c++, qt, audio

I want to make a music player and I want to filter out files not audio file on opening.
Should I use QAudioDecoder?
But every file I checked with QAudioDecoder tells me the same codec "audio/pcm".

```
QAudioDecoder decoder;
decoder.setSourceFilename(fileUrl.toLocalFile());
qDebug() << decoder.audioFormat().codec();
```

How do I know if the audio file's format is supported by Qt media player by not just checking if the file's name ends with ".mp3" or ".wav"?

And I found that some files' duration incorrect when playing on my music player. 
But when I play the file with other music player apps, it gives correct duration on other music players.

Or my app can't play some files but others can.
the console says :

> DirectShowPlayerService::doSetUrlSource: Unresolved error code
>   0x80070002 (?t?Χ??????w?????C)

but after I change the file name, it can be opened.

How should I fix those on my music player instead of fixing the files' probably wrong or unsupported formats one by one?

---

I wrote this code to check if the file I opened is a supported audio file.

```
QMediaPlayer audioChecker;
audioChecker.setMedia(fileUrl);
qDebug() << audioChecker.media().canonicalUrl().fileName();
qDebug() << audioChecker.isAudioAvailable();
if(audioChecker.error() == QMediaPlayer::NoError) {
    qDebug() << "no error";
}
if(audioChecker.error() == QMediaPlayer::FormatError) {
    qDebug() << "format error";
}
```

and it tells me no error no matter what file I tested.

console:

> "musicplayer.exe"
>   false
>   no error
>   "musicplayer.exe"
>   false
>   no error
>   "musicplayer.ilk"
>   false
>   no error
>   "musicplayer.exe"
>   false
>   no error
>   "a song.mp3"
>   false
>   no error

But how can files not audio file get no error?
Why do audio file's audio not available?

---

Never mind. I just read that setMedia() return immediately and doesn't wait for the media to be loaded. so it's normal it gets no audio and no error because it's not loaded.
I guess I'll make a thread class to check my file.

By the way, incorrect duration of the file is fixed somehow. Does it relate to LAV Splitter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Qt's documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/audiooverview.html):

> For playing media or audio files that are not simple, uncompressed audio, you can use the `QMediaPlayer` C++ class […] The compressed audio formats supported does depend on the operating system environment, and also what media plugins the user may have installed.

A simple example of how to use the `QMediaPlayer` class:

```
player = new QMediaPlayer;
// ...
player->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("/Users/me/Music/coolsong.mp3"));
player->setVolume(50);
player->play();
```

To verify that the codec is supported, you can use the `error()` method of the `QMediaPlayer` class which will return you an error code (see the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaplayer.html#Error-enum)).

So, after calling `setMedia()`, you can do something like:

```
if (player->error() == QMediaPlayer::FormatError)
{
    // Codec/format unsupported
}
```

---

About the error code you get when opening files:

- check that you have no `\` characters in your path (if you have some, escape them with another `\`)
- check if you have spaces, special characters, etc.

Answer (score 0):

1. About how to check audio format in file without check its suffix, there's a tool names [mediainfo](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo/Download), with the command line tool run as below:

   ```
   mediainfo -f [filepath]
   ```

   You'll get the full information about the file, both video and audio if they exists. And among these parameters, there's a "format" value under "Audio" category, that indicates the actual audio format inside. eg. AAC/AC3
2. About the file can be played after name changed, I consider maybe there are some space characters in the filename, or the Player just can't access the file specified by name.

Comment: Thanks, I'll looking into how to use mediainfo in my app.

Comment: Since you are using Qt framework, so I guess that your target app may be an executable binary file, and if then you should research the libmediainfo module, that provides functions with a static lib.